# is it possible to add verical plot line and show the intersection with the series?

Tags: highcharts

I want to know if there is a way to put a line on the chart and show the values that intersect this line from all the series

to do so I've created a formatter for the series data labels that look for each label if it's x value is the x value of the plot line and then only show the data label

```
plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                className: 'highcharts-data-label-box',
                                padding: 0,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    if (valuesToShow.indexOf(this.x) > -1) {
                                        return this.y;
                                    } else {
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
}
```

this is my demo for this:
    https://jsfiddle.net/rabigado/7wousgm5/118/

would love to find a way to do so with annotations or some other less costly way to achive the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom labels can be made using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`. However, it requires additional logic while the chart is redrawn, because labels change their positions and what is more difficult dataGrouping approximates different values when extremes will change.

I managed to make it, you can follow this approach:

1. in `point.events.click` callback find the x position from the whole
   group of points. You can find it in `chart.series.xData` array.
   Notice, that `chart.series.processedXData` has values that are currently rendered on the chart - grouped by dataGrouping.
2. render plotLine on the x position
3. use `chart.renderer.text` to add a label for each series. Save the
   reference to the created label.
4. in the `chart.events.render` callback destroy existing SVG elements
   for each label and redraw it with a new position and new value when dataGrouping will change it.

**Code:**

**adding labels when point is clicked:**

```
point: {
  events: {
    click(event) {
      var chart = this.series.chart,
        seriesLen = chart.series.length,
        x = this.x,
        pointIndex,
        pointIndexAbs,
        i,
        y,
        annotation,
        absX,
        plotLine;

      absX = chart.series[0].xData.reduce(
        (prev, curr, index) => {
          return Math.abs(curr - x) < Math.abs(prev - x) ? curr : prev;
        });

      plotLine = chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
        color: "#000",
        width: 1,
        value: absX,
        id: absX
      });

      for (i = 0; i < seriesLen - 1; i++) {

        pointIndex = chart.series[i].processedXData.indexOf(x);

        if (pointIndex !== -1) {
          y = chart.series[i].processedYData[pointIndex];

          annotation = chart.renderer.text(
              y.toFixed(4).toString(),
              chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(absX) - 25,
              chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y)
            )
            .css({
              fill: 'red',
              fontSize: '10px'
            })
            .attr({
              zIndex: 6
            })
            .add();

          chart.annotationColl.push({
            svgElem: annotation,
            x: absX,
            y: y,
            seriesIndex: i,
            plotLine: plotLine
          });
        }
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**redraw labels on render event:**

```
chart: {
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    render: function() {
      var chart = this,
        x,
        newX,
        newY,
        actualValue,
        absX,
        pointIndex,
        y;

      if (chart.annotationColl && chart.annotationColl.length) {

        chart.annotationColl.forEach(function(annotation, i) {
          if (annotation.svgElem) {
            annotation.svgElem.destroy();
          }

          absX = chart.series[0].processedXData.reduce(
            (prev, curr, index) => {
              return Math.abs(curr - annotation.x) < Math.abs(prev - annotation.x) ? curr : prev;
            });

          pointIndex = chart.series[annotation.seriesIndex].processedXData.indexOf(absX);
          y = chart.series[annotation.seriesIndex].processedYData[pointIndex];

          newX = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(annotation.x) - 25;
          newY = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y);

          if (newX >= chart.plotLeft && newX < chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth - 35) {
            annotation.svgElem = chart.renderer.text(
                y.toFixed(4).toString(),
                newX,
                newY
              )
              .css({
                fill: 'red',
                fontSize: '10px'
              })
              .attr({
                zIndex: 6
              })
              .add();
          } else {
            annotation.svgElem = null;
          }
        });
      } else {
        chart.annotationColl = [];
      }

    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zgsh7r4d/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.render
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#destroy